# Mail subject decoding?

Tags: email, encoding, mime

I have a email subject like this:

`Subject: =?gbk?Q?=B3=F6=C3=C0=C1=E2=C7=BF=C1=A6=B3=E9=CA=AA=BB=FA=D2=BB=CC=A8?=
 =?gbk?Q?=A3=AC=D6=E9=BA=A3=B9=E3=D6=DD=C9=FA=BB=EE=B1=D8=B1=B8?=`

But I don't know what kind of encoding is this?
Could someone help? Newbie to email protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This subject is encoded in [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK), an extension of the GB2312 character set for simplified Chinese characters, used in the People's Republic of China.

As defined in the [RFC1342 specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1342.txt), to represent non-ASCII text in Internet Message headers, you have to encode it with the [MIME encoded-word syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word):

> encoded-word = "=" "?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?" "="
>
> charset = token    ; legal charsets defined by RFC 1341
>
> encoding = token   ; Either "B" or "Q"
>
> token = 1*
>
> tspecials = "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" / "," / ";" / ":" / "\" /
>                  <"> / "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "." / "="
>
> encoded-text = 1* (but see "Use of encoded-words in message
>                     ; headers", below)
>
> ---
>
> The "B" encoding:
>
> > The "B" encoding is identical to the "BASE64" encoding defined by
> >     RFC
> >        1341.
>
> The "Q" encoding:
>
> > The "Q" encoding is similar to the "Quoted-Printable" content-
> >     transfer-encoding defined in RFC 1341.  It is designed to allow text
> >     containing mostly ASCII characters to be decipherable on an ASCII
> >     terminal without decoding.
> >
> > > (1) Any 8-bit value may be represented by a "=" followed by two
> > >              hexadecimal digits.  For example, if the character set in use
> > >              were ISO-8859-1, the "=" character would thus be encoded as
> > >              "=3D", and a SPACE by "=20".  (Upper case should be used for
> > >              hexadecimal digits "A" through "F".)
> > >
> > > (2) The 8-bit hexadecimal value 20 (e.g., ISO-8859-1 SPACE) may be
> > >              represented as "*" (underscore, ASCII 95.).  (This character may
> > >              not pass through some internetwork mail gateways, but its use
> > >              will greatly enhance readability of "Q" encoded data with mail
> > >              readers that do not support this encoding.)  Note that the "*"
> > >              always represents hexadecimal 20, even if the SPACE character
> > >              occupies a different code position in the character set in use.
> > >
> > > (3) 8-bit values which correspond to printable ASCII characters
> > >       other
> > >              than "=", "?", and "_" (underscore), MAY be represented as those
> > >              characters.  (But see section 5 for restrictions.)  In
> > >              particular, SPACE and TAB MUST NOT be represented as themselves
> > >              within encoded words.

In your subject:

> Subject:
>   =?gbk?Q?=B3=F6=C3=C0=C1=E2=C7=BF=C1=A6=B3=E9=CA=AA=BB=FA=D2=BB=CC=A8?=  =?gbk?Q?=A3=AC=D6=E9=BA=A3=B9=E3=D6=DD=C9=FA=BB=EE=B1=D8=B1=B8?=

We can see that the [Quoted-Printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding has been used, hence the presence of `=` as escape character instead of `%`.

You can find an online encode [here](https://mothereff.in/q), and an online MIME Headers Decoder [here](http://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/).

Finally, here is your decoded subject:

> Subject: 出美菱强力抽湿机一台，珠海广州生活必备

Comment: @holys: Because this is quoted-printable encoding, which is not quite the same as URL encoding. Emails are MIME documents and MIME does not even have a concept of URL encoding.